# what does this syntax mean in php: if ( $matches->match_is_editable( $ts ) )

Tags: php, syntax

I am finally grasping most of the syntax in php but examples like this one I do not seem to understand what it means:

```
   if ( $matches->match_is_editable( $ts ) )
```

This is what I understad:

`"$matches"` is a variable

`"->"` means that is part of the same object but confused how its supposed to relate to the next part

`"match_is_editable"` is a function

`"($ts)"` is a variable called to work in inside that function

can you please correct where I am wrong? Will be highly appreciated

Comment: matches is an object, google php oop. The function belongs to the object and `->` is how php identifies object functions/variables

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$matches->match_is_editable( $ts )
```

The `->` accesses an object's method (what we call functions when they belong to objects) or property. This means two things:

1. `$matches` is a handle to an object. Somewhere earlier in the code you will find `$matches = new ClassName()` (if *ClassName* is the name of the object's class)
2. `match_is_editable` must be a method or a property in `ClassName`

In this case, since it takes the argument `$ts`, we can deduce that it's not a property, but a method. Here is what the class might look like:

```
Class ClassName{
    public function match_is_editable($arg){
        ...
    }
}
```

So **the top line means**: Access the object referred to by `$matches` and execute its `match_is_editable` method, passing it the argument `$ts`.